# SSRS 2019 Report Renders but does not export to csv

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working with SSRS 2019 and VS 2019. We have a number of SSRS reports that render, can export to Excel, and export as a CSV without a problem. However, one report will render, export to Excel, but when exporting to a CSV even though it has data in the report it is empty. I am at a loss for why this would happen. Any suggestions?

This happens whether I Preview this report in Visual Studio or run it thought SSRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way that fixed this for me was I went to the Properties of my Tablix, I set the DataElementOutput from NoOutput to Output. Then it exported to csv just fine.

Comment: Hmm - mine defaults to Auto.